# How can i write array with the same function in its elements?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm trying to write an array of this kind

[image: Coefficients]
 phi(m,r) and dphi(m,r) are functions, where cheby and dcheby are Chebyshev polynomials and its derivates respectively,

```
  Real(kind=8) FUNCTION phi(m,r)
  implicit none 
  integer m
  real(kind=8) r
  real(kind=8) cheby

  if(mod(m,2).eq.0) then
  phi = cheby(m+2,r)-cheby(0,r)
  else if (mod(m,2).eq.1) then 
  phi = cheby(m+2,r) - cheby(1,r)
  end if
  end FUNCTION phi

  Real(kind=8) FUNCTION dphi(m,r)
  implicit none 
   integer m
   real(kind=8) r
   real(kind=8) dcheby  
   if(mod(m,2).eq.0) then
   dphi = dcheby(m+2,r) - dcheby(0,r)
   else if (mod(m,2).eq.1) then 
   dphi = dcheby(m+2,r) - dcheby(1,r)
   end if 
  end FUNCTION dphi
```

so first i  define g  and then i used 2nd order- simpson's rule to integrate

```
Real(kind=8) FUNCTION g(j,i,r)
       implicit none 
       integer i,j
       real(kind=8) r
       real(kind=8) dphi, phi
       real(kind=8) lambda

       g = -dphi(j,r)*dphi(i,r) + lambda*phi(j,r)*phi(i,r)

end FUNCTION g 


Real(kind=8) FUNCTION integrate(j,i)
   implicit none 
   integer i, j
   real(kind=8) g
   Real(kind=8) xmax, xmin
   xmax = 1.0d0
   xmin = -1.0d0 

   integrate =(( xmax -  xmin)/6)*(g(j,i,xmin) +4*g(j,i,0.0d0) + g(j,i,xmax)) 

end FUNCTION integrate
```

However i don't  know how write the matrix, i wrote that

```
 do i=0,N
     do l=0,N
       A(i,l) = integrate(j,i)
     end do
 end do
```

but, when I compiled A= NaN

Comment: Can you add your functions `phi` and `dphi` to make the example complete?

Comment: So now we have to find `cheby` and `dcheby`?

Comment: @albert means that for a proper question so we can help, we need a complete, compilable piece of code.

Comment: So, I've used a program with cheby and dcheby, however I'll upload complete code.

Comment: @kabanus Here is complete program https://github.com/dayacaca/Computational_Physics/blob/master/M%C3%A9todos%20Espectrales/Galerkin/Helmholtz/Helmholtz.f90

Comment: @kabanus indeed that is what I meant, maybe a bit cynic. After the question / comment about `phi` and `dphi` the unknown functions `cheby` and `dcheby` surfaced.

Comment: Do not use kind=8  everywhere, it is just hurting my eyes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter Try toi ue some meaningful indentation to make the structure apparent.

Comment: you should reduce your problem to a [mcve] so we could help you. As it is presented now, you declare `real(kind=8) cheby`. This is a real-type scalar, not a local function. Please, provide a testable code.

Comment: I recommend that you break up the problem in smaller parts. The nan value that you obtain follows from a loop that calls the polynials behind the integration routine. First check that you polynomial functions and derivatives give the expected result, then test out the integration routine at specified values of the arguments, and finally you can try to build the full program.